# How to handle sorting with infinite scroll on aggregated lists

Tags: sql, arrays, mongodb

Context:
I have chat conversations stored in mongo.
I have 'mails' conversations (that's how we name them) in sql.

I need to make a list of conversations (mails + chat) and we need infinite scrolling

My problem is the following: Let's say that on each call we get 3 mails and 3 chats.
On first call

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Chat (created date)</td>
     <td>Mail (created date)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
     <td>7 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
     <td>6 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
     <td>3 nov</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Concatenated</p>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Chat + Mail</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>7 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>6 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>5 nov</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>3 nov</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, if on second call I'll get a chat the is created 5 nov, that chat well get above the last mail, and not under.

How should I handle this kind of stuff ? My other idea is to use a 1 week delimited between calls instead of fixed number of conversations...
But this one can return me 0 results for a particular week.